# object declared with no type not being raised as an error by typescript

Tags: typescript

I have the following tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "types": ["node", "jest"]
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*.ts", "./src/**/*.tsx"],
  "plugins": [
    {
      "name": "typescript-tslint-plugin"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have `noImplicitAny` set but typescript is instead inferring the type for this object:

```
export const routes = [
    {
        exact: true,
        id: "home",
        main: {
            component: Home,
        },
        path: "/",
    },
    {
        id: "audit-report",
        main: {
            component: AuditReport,
        },
        path: "/reports/audit",
    },
];
```

I would have expected an error to be raised for this object as it is not typed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`noImplictAny` triggers errors only when the type is not specified **AND** typescript implicitly assumes `any` because it has no extra information about the variable. In your case while the type is not specified typescript can easily infer the type for `routes`. If you use it improperly (ie you access non-existent properties) you will get an error, so this is all type safe as far as the compiler is concerned.

I generally recommend letting the compiler infer types where it can, typing everything explicitly adds a lot of noise, and I find it is of limited value (you can see inferred types by hovering if you really need to know the inferred type)

If you really really really want to force all types to be specified you can use [this](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/typedef/) tslint rule.

Comment: the type widening makes this annoying.  i can add a property that is in one object and not the other and get no error

Comment: @dagda1 true, that can be a problem. You can specify the type explictly.. ex: `routes: IRouteOptions[]`. Otherwise for arrays TS will try do find a type that makes all items ok, even if that type is a union.

Comment: that is what i normally do but i’m in a new contract and was just surprised